# On hover, div border is showing, despite same CSS as non-hover

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have subscription page (rails 4, bootstrap 3) where I'm setting the following divs:

```
<ul class="thumbnails koudoku-pricing-table">
  <% @plans.each do |plan| %>
    <li class="col-md-3 plan <%= 'plan-primary' if plan.highlight? %>">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <div class="caption"> 
          <h3><%= plan.name %></h3>
          <h4><%= plan_price(plan) %></h4>
          <div class="call-to-action">
```

My CSS for the classes is:

```
ul.koudoku-pricing-table {

  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;


  li.plan {

    text-align: center;
    padding: 0; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    z-index: 99;


    &.plan-primary {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin-top: 0px;
      padding: 0;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      z-index: 100;
    }

      h3 {
        font-size: 32.5px;
        line-height: 51px;
      }
      h4 {
        line-height: 22px;
      }
      a, input[type=submit] {
        font-size: 21.5px;
        line-height: 26px;
      }
      ul.features {
        padding: 0 1em;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        li {
          font-size: 12pt;
        }

    }


    .call-to-action {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .features {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 8px;
        line-height: 18px;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
      }
      li:first-child {
        border-top: none;
      }
    }

  }


  .social-proof {
    padding: 17px 0;
    blockquote {
      h2, h3, h4 {
        padding: 5px 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .img-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #b0b2ab;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #b0b2ab;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #b0b2ab;
}


.img-thumbnail:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #3399f3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #3399f3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #3399f3;
}


.thumbnail .caption {
  padding: 0px;
  color: #666666;
}
}
```

As you can see, for the .img-thumbnail:hover and .img-thumbnail, the only difference is the background color (white vs grey) and the box-shadow (grey vs blue).

My issue is that when I hover over one of the img-thumbnail boxes, the outline of the underlying div container is visible on the left side an right side of the highlighted box (looks like a rail up either side, but more visible on the left in the image below):
[image]

These outlines are not visible when the box isn't highlighted:

[image]

How can I hide this outline?

Comment: Can you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem? Because I compiled your sass (there's one missing `}` on ln48 that I fixed) and it looks like it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/K8QUp/

Comment: I created a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ns1/RNAMM/), however the issue isn't visible on jsFiddle.

Comment: Umm ... sorry to be blunt, but that's not very useful then, is it? :) do you have a link to this page where this is happening?

Comment: Fair feedback; unfortunately I don't have a live page to share.  Appreciate the help regardless.

Comment: For a start you should get rid of any issues that might be arising from css over-specificity by only targeting using classnames (e.g. use .plan not li.plan) and don't nest more than three levels deep. Secondly, when declaring pseudo-classes (e.g. :hover) you don't need to rewrite any CSS properties except for the ones that change (e.g. .img-thumbnail:hover should just contain background-color and box-shadow declarations). Maybe that might help you get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Okay so, theory ... if your images are exactly lined up, and the only difference is the hover, that means that there's a parent element to `.img-thumbnail` that is also being triggered by its own `:hover` -- because the grey shadow surrounding the element is **bigger** than the blue shadow surrounding the `.img-thumbnail`. So I would *guess* you have a shadow affecting the `li` that `.img-thumbnail` sits inside (in the form of `li.plan:hover` I'd say.)

Comment: Setek- your theory was fact!  There was a plan:hover in a separate stylesheet that was causing the issue. Rookie mistake on my part.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and I fixed it by adding the remaining subclasses: link, visited and active, in your case, you must define something like:

```
.img-thumbnail:link {
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #b0b2ab;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #b0b2ab;
box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px #b0b2ab;
}
```

Remember that once hover is triggered, it will not fall back automatically to the default state you have defined.

Comment: After implementing this solution, I'm still seeing the rails on either side.

Comment: :hover is a pseudo-class meaning it's a special state of an element. When hover is 'triggered' it will be in the hover state but when you're not hovering over the element its state will be the default state. Adding the :link, :visited, and :active pseudo-classes should not affect :hover as they are independent states.